# How many of the zodiac constellations can we see during the summer solstice?

Tags: constellations, zodiac

I've read on James Evans' excellent "The History and Practice of Ancient Astronomy" that it is possible to see (at night) 6 zodiac constellations all year round, even during the summer solstice. I'm unsure how this is possible if the days are longer and the nights are shorter. Can somebody help me understand this, please?

Comment: The Sun blocks half the sky. If the half that you can see is dark (night time), you can see half the zodiacal constellations. Approximately.

Comment: Doesn't it block more than half the sky in summer?

Comment: It might be roughly true for where most people lived at the time, but obviously in the arctics the sun can be up for 24 hours.

Comment: Let's say at 45°N

Comment: Just used Stellarium, it shows Tarus, Pisces, Aquarius, Capricornus, Sagitarius, Libra, Virgo, Leo, Cancer, and Gemini all at least partly visible on June 21 at 45N.  It makes sense that at any given instant, you'd see about half of them, and more as the Earth rotates.  When the Sun comes up, it blocks out constellations you've already seen, so it does not block half the sky all of the time.

Comment: You always see half the sky at night, no matter what time of the year it is, no matter where the Sun is. So, unless you’re north of the Arctic Circle or south of the Antarctic Circle, you will see half the ecliptic no matter where you are, no matter the date.